# Upper bound on Sum of square roots

Tags: maxima-minima, sums-of-squares

Let $k_1,k_2\ldots k_t$ be integers and $\sum_{i=1}^{t}{k_i}=k$ where $k$ is fixed.
What is the maximum value of $\sum_{i=1}^{t}\sqrt{k_i}$.

Comment: Do you know of the [Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality?

Comment: Cauchy Schwarz says $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_ix_i\right)^2\le\left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_i^2\right)$ can you think of good choices for $y_i$ and $x_i$?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is a direct application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Hint:
consider $v=(1,\dots,1)$ and $w=(\sqrt{k_1},\dots,\sqrt{k_t})$ and use
$$
|\langle v,w \rangle|^2\le\|v\|_2\|w\|_2
$$